# Two Cisco VPNs on One PC?

Tags: cisco-vpn-client

I have to access two remote systems via Cisco VPN. It's really painful, as I have to keep switching between two remote machines on two different VPNs.

I know Cisco VPN only runs one instance per PC, but **is there a way to run two VPNs and remote simultaneously to two PCs?** I have two internet connections (one wired, one wireless).

Maybe through a virtual machine for one VPN+RemoteDesktop, and natively connect to the other from Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure its possible, but you won't like how you have to do it:  virtual machines.  Put each cisco client in it's own virtual machine, and your main machine will act like a dumb network switch from the perspective the vpn client.

Comment: Maybe it would be worth it if I had two monitors. Sigh.

Comment: @ashes999: Why do you need two monitors for that?

Comment: @grawity because I need to see the two systems side-by-side :O

Comment: @ashes999: To use two VPNs? You don't, if you can get one of the machines to act as a router... _somehow_.

Comment: +1 for *possible, but you're not gonna like it*. It's the true answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround without using VMs: there is an open source replacement of Cisco AnyConnect, it is called [OpenConnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/) and it is partially compatible with AnyConnect.

A problem may be that it does not implement the feature to scan the endpoint configuration, so if it is enforced, the OpenConnect client will not connect.

If that is not required, both AnyConnect and OpenConnect can work in parallel.